# How to update 'updated_at' of model when updating a pivot table

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, many-to-many

I'm using laravel and I have a many to many relation between products and orders. There is a pivot table called order-product which has additional information that is updated from time to time. I would like to update the 'updated_at' feild in the order table when the corresponding row in the pivot table is updated or for example if a new product is added. 
Is that possible?

The relation between a products and an order is belongsToMany()

Edit: here is some of the code

```
class Order extends Model
{ 
protected $table = 'order';
protected $dates = ['updated_at'];

 public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_product');
    }
}
```

When I want to remove products its by calling
$order->products()->detach()

So where do I put the $touches array thats mentioned in the laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps)

I've tried adding it to the product model but its not working.

Comment: Check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Touching Parent Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps), here is an example (from laravel docs).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * All of the relationships to be touched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $touches = ['post'];

    /**
     * Get the post that the comment belongs to.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. I think thats because I'm updating the pivot table not one of the models.

Comment: Well you use a belongsToMany()->withPivot() right, that should still work as it just returns a relation, it works for me at least

Comment: I added protected $touches = ['order']; to the product model. Maybe Im not putting it in the right place??

Comment: is your relation also called `order`?

Comment: the models are called 'order' and 'product'. The pivot table is called 'order_product'.

Comment: yea but like where you do $this->belongsToMany()->withPivot(); what's the name of the function?, that's what the value in the array should be

Comment: Oh I see. I've been doing it wrong then. I'll do it again and get back on the results. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123360/discussion-between-user3552551-and-neat).